# How to check AWS lambda handler in unit test python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to write a unit test for the AWS lambda handler. I want to give some JSON files to the handler method and get some output. But I come across trouble with mocking the S3 "event".
My lambda handler looks like this:

```
def handler(event, context):
    print(f'Event: {event}')

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(event["bucket"])

    word_correction = correction.WordCorrection()

    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        key = obj.key
        body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
        data = get_data_from_file(body)

        if key.endswith('.json'):
            try:
                word_correction.create_duplicated_words_file(data)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return {
                    "success": False,
                    "response": f"Failed to read file - {e}"
                }
            try:
                corrected_word_list = word_correction.spell_words(json.loads(body))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return {
                    "success": False,
                    "response": f"Failed to correct words - {e}"
                }
        else:
            return {
                "success": False,
                "response": "Invalid file type. File must have .json extension."
            }
        return {
            "success": True,
            "response": corrected_word_list
        }
```

Here I put some JSON data to my module word_correction.
From this point my unit test

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME = 'dev-ayazv-lambda-spell-correction'
DEFAULT_REGION = 'us-east-1'

S3_TEST_FILE_KEY = 'pdfs/manual_test/page-data-page-9.json'
S3_TEST_FILE_CONTENT = {"Blocks": [{"BlockType": "WORD", "Confidence": 93.18, "Text": "Test"}]}


@mock_s3
class TestLambdaFunction(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=DEFAULT_REGION)
        self.s3_bucket = self.s3.create_bucket(Bucket=S3_BUCKET_NAME)
        self.s3_bucket.put_object(Key=S3_TEST_FILE_KEY,
                                  Body=json.dumps(S3_TEST_FILE_CONTENT))

    def test_get_data_from_file(self):
        from functions.spell_correction.src.index import get_data_from_file

        json_encode_data = json.dumps(S3_TEST_FILE_CONTENT, indent=2).encode('utf-8')
        file_content = get_data_from_file(json_encode_data)

        self.assertEqual(file_content, S3_TEST_FILE_CONTENT)

    def test_handler(self):
        from functions.spell_correction.src.index import handler

        event = {
            'bucket': {
                'name': S3_BUCKET_NAME
            },
            'object': {
                'key': S3_TEST_FILE_KEY
            }
        }

        result = handler(event, {})
        self.assertEqual(result, {"success": True, "response": []})
```

I was trying to mock the S3_Bucket S3_File_Key and S3_File Content.
But I face with the problem that my tests drops in this moment

```
bucket = {'name': 'dev-ayazv-lambda-spell-correction'}

    def validate_bucket_name(params, **kwargs):
        if 'Bucket' not in params:
            return
        bucket = params['Bucket']
>       if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):
E       TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: For what it's worth SAM templates are a good reference for unit and integration tests for Lambdas. You can get them using the SAM CLI or just examine the repo: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli-app-templates.